How Can I Load CSV File in PySpark by Matching Column Names with the Schema?
I am loading multiple CSV files using Python Spark. Below is the code:
spark.read.format("csv").option("header", 'true').schema(table_schema).load(file_path)

In this code, I am explicitly providing table_schema at the time of loading. However, my problem is that the DataFrame is getting created based on the order of the columns instead of comparing the column names between the schema and the actual CSV file.
Is there a way to load CSV files into a DataFrame by matching the column names in table_schema with the CSV file header row?

Could you share the table_schema as well? Also, please provide a minimal reproducible example.
